# How to use the LAG in SQL Server within a group?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is a list of different people and their occupation before they became zombies. I need to find the occupation just before the person became a zombie. The last individual became a zombie, then reverted back to zoo keeper and finally became a zombie again. In this case, I just need the occupation just before the first zombie transformation.

Recordset:

```
Person    Occupation    Order_of_events
---------------------------------------
1         Lawyer        1
1         Dog Walker    2
1         Zoo Keeper    3
1         Zombie        4
1         Driver        5
2         Lifeguard     1
2         Zombie        2
3         Zoo Keeper    1
3         Zombie        2
3         Driver        3
3         Zombie        4
```

Final Result

```
Person    Occupation
---------------------
1         Zoo Keeper
2         Lifeguard
3         Zoo Keeper
```

My attempt:

```
SELECT 
    person, occupation, Order_of_events,
    LAG(occupation, 1, 'Always a zombie') OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY Order_of_events) AS [previous occupation]
FROM 
    table
```

I think my issue is in the partition but I am getting confused on how to select the previous row where zombie was the occupation.

I'm using SQL Server 2017.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually need `lag()` for this.  But window functions will help:

```
select top (1) with ties tprev.*
from t join
     t tprev
     on t.person = tprev.person 
    and t.Order_of_events = tprev.Order_of_events + 1
where t.occupation = 'Zombie'
order by row_number() over (partition by t.person order by t.Order_of_events);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using LEAD to search for one row in the remaining list for "zombie" and do a group by to eliminate dupes (take the first found occupation for id). This could work without the self-join solution.